# XQuery amalgamating repeating XML structures

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

I am trying to figure out how I can amalgamate any of the repeating structures below where 'code' is the same. I want to sum the number_of_units and value_of_units elements where code matches. Also, keep the distinct 'books' in the result set i.e code T101 would remain in the example below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<book_breakdown>
        <book>
           <name>Life of Pi</name>
           <code>T348</code>
           <unit_price>
              <price currency='GBP'>11.99</price>
           </unit_price>
      <unit_holding>
              <number_of_units>14</number_of_units>
              <value_of_units>159.92</value_of_units>
        <unit_holding>
        </book>
        <book>
           <name>Catcher in the rye</name>
           <code>T101</code>
           <unit_price>
              <price currency='GBP'>10.99</price>
           </unit_price>
             <unit_holding>
              <number_of_units>14</number_of_units>
              <value_of_units>159.92</value_of_units>
        <unit_holding>
        </book>
      <book>
           <name>Life of Pi</name>
           <code>T348</code>
           <unit_price>
              <price currency='GBP'>11.50</price>
           </unit_price>
       <unit_holding>
              <number_of_units>13</number_of_units>
              <value_of_units>129.92</value_of_units>
        <unit_holding>
        </book>
     </book_breakdown>
```

Comment: Do you want a solution in XSLT or XQuery? What have you already tried yourself? Also your example XML is not wellformed (missing namespace URI for `ns0` and wrong quotes in attributes).

Comment: It is a grouping problem, please also state the version of XSLT or XQuery you can use as grouping constructs (e.g. `for-each-group` in XSLT 2.0, `group by` in XQuery 3.0) make it easier in current versions of those language than in earlier versions.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. XQuery ideally. I've tried a few things with not much luck, last thing I tried was something like storing the nondistinct codes then - for loop -> where nondistinct, return structure with sum(numofunits), sum(valueofunits).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm doing this in Oracle Service Bus 11g, which uses XQuery 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fn:distinct-values(...)` to get all unique `code`s and then rebuild the document from them:

```
<book_breakdown>{
  for $code in distinct-values(//book/code)
  order by $code
  let $books := //book[code = $code]
  return <book>{
    $books[1]/(name, code),
    <unit_price>{
      (: do something sensible with differing/matching prices here :)
      $books/unit_price/price
    }</unit_price>,
    <unit_holding>
      <number_of_units>{sum($books//number_of_units)}</number_of_units>
      <value_of_units>{sum($books//value_of_units)}</value_of_units>
    </unit_holding>
  }</book>
}</book_breakdown>
```

This results in the following document:

```
<book_breakdown>
  <book>
    <name>Catcher in the rye</name>
    <code>T101</code>
    <unit_price>
      <price currency="GBP">10.99</price>
    </unit_price>
    <unit_holding>
      <number_of_units>14</number_of_units>
      <value_of_units>159.92</value_of_units>
    </unit_holding>
  </book>
  <book>
    <name>Life of Pi</name>
    <code>T348</code>
    <unit_price>
      <price currency="GBP">11.99</price>
      <price currency="GBP">11.50</price>
    </unit_price>
    <unit_holding>
      <number_of_units>27</number_of_units>
      <value_of_units>289.84</value_of_units>
    </unit_holding>
  </book>
</book_breakdown>
```

Comment: Thats great thanks. I've tried testing it myself, but get a " ": can not cast to double. Invalid double value. Trying to debug where this might be occurring.

Comment: Adding the full Xpath to number_of_units and value_of_units, seems to have solved that one.